# How to find the return type in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have  doubt regarding getting the return type's .

```
class SampleOnOUTandREF
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(typeof(int));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

If i write this the output is System.Int32.

But in my application i want the result as "int" if i give "System.Int32".
Please help regarding this issue.In my application i am using System.Reflection for reading .dll's .

Answer (score 5):

`int` is a C#-specific keyword.

The Reflection library is language-neutral and is unaware of C#-specific keywords.

Instead, you can write a `Dictionary<Type, string>` to contain the C# keyword types.

Answer (score 3):

Section 4.1.4 of the C# spec lists all of the value types that C# has reserved words for and 4.2 mentions the classes that have aliases:

```
object: System.Object
string: System.String
sbyte: System.SByte
byte: System.Byte
short: System.Int16
ushort: System.UInt16
int: System.Int32
uint: System.UInt32
long: System.Int64
ulong: System.UInt64
char: System.Char
float: System.Single
double: System.Double
bool: System.Boolean 
decimal: System.Decimal
```

As SLaks mentions, you can have a dictionary mapping CLR types to C# types, like this:

```
new Dictionary<string, string> {
{ "System.SByte", "sbyte" },
{ "System.Byte", "byte" },
...
```

or like this:

```
new Dictionary<Type, string> {
{ typeof(sbyte), "sbyte" },
{ typeof(byte), "byte" },
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I will reword what others have said; I still think I can add value:.

`int` is not the name of a type; it is a C# keyword that the compiler treats as a synonym for the type `System.Int32`. You can think it this way: once your code is compiled, all references to `int` are gone, and replaced by references to `System.Int32`. `System.Int32` is part of the [CTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e(v=VS.100).aspx), and that is what `typeof` or `GetType` will refer to.

Answer (score 0):

The C# keyword `int` is just an alias for `System.Int32`. Similarly, `bool` is an alias for `System.Boolean` and `string` is an alias for `System.String`.

Since these are all aliases and not actual types you will never see them returned by reflection. However, the types that are returned are completely equivalent.